# Git not add files to repository

Tags: git

I have repository on bitbucket. When I import new module,I cannot add the files and folder to repository.
In bitbucket here's how it looks:
 [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoK3U.png)

The path MemorizingTrustManager  is empty, I cannot add folders and files under that to repository. I'm using git add * but it doens't work.
Please help me. Thanks

Comment: use - `git add .` from the project's root directory

Comment: Are you trying to use git submodules? If so you need to do `git submodule init` and `git submodule update` from the main repo's root.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
git add .
```

Then you have to

```
git commit -m "something"
```

Then

```
git push <branch> <ref>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should go to MemorizingTrustManager folder. and looking for `.git` folder and delete it.

After that, you go back to rood folder and do some add command

`git add .`

`git commit -m 'add something'`